# Visual Studio Extension: Compile file with VCFileConfiguration fails

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a simple C# Visual Studio extension in which I need to compile C++ files with the current project configuration. I tried to use [VCFileConfiguration.Compile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcfileconfiguration.compile.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) for this task. It works fine if I set the waitOnBuild parameter to false. If I set it true to achieve a blocking call, I get a Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectException exception, no matter if the file can be compiled without errors or not.

Is this a bug or is there anything special I need to setup?

My code so far (stripped error handling):

```cs
var projectItem = dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem;
var project = projectItem.ContainingProject;
VCProject vcProject = (VCProject)project.Object;
VCConfiguration activeConfiguration = vcProject.ActiveConfiguration;

VCFile vcFile = projectItem.Object as VCFile;
IVCCollection fileConfigCollection = vcFile.FileConfigurations;
VCFileConfiguration fileConfig = fileConfigCollection.Item(activeConfiguration.Name);
try
{
    fileConfig.Compile(false, true);
}
catch (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectException exception)
{
    // Fails all the time if waitOnBuild == true
}
```

The exception in Detail:

- *Message*: "The build failed."
- *Source*: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.v14.0"

Callstack:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowProjectExceptionHelper(Exception innerException, String unformattedMessage, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowProjectException(String message)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCFileConfigurationShim.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<Compile>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.ApartmentMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<Invoke>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.ApartmentMarshaler.Invoke(Func`1 method)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCFileConfigurationShim.Compile(Boolean forceBuild, Boolean waitOnBuild)
at IncludeFormatter.Commands.PurgeIncludes.MenuItemCallback(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Andreas\Development\current_development\IncludeFormatter\IncludeFormatter\Commands\PurgeIncludes.cs:line 144
```

Comment: It might help to share the exception message and stack.

Comment: Good point! Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Could you please check if there are inner exceptions or other details in the exception?

Comment: I guess the error is not in Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.v14.0, since it's just happens to be an exception helper.

Comment: Sadly there aren't inner exceptions or any other further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take a glimpse of the internal code: Both options are explicitly deprecated and the error is filed as a documentation/api bug.

Answer (score 1):

*First*: Try **Restarting Visual Studio and your computer** - this is the most common solution for your problem.

*If the above doesn't help*: Try to clean the solution and remove "vspscc" and "vssscc" files, and then restart VS and "Rebuild All".

*Final option*: In Visual Studio "

> Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build and Run setting area:
>   Try to change
>
> "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to **"Diagnostic"**

so you can determine what is failing in your project.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem in any way - the files in question compile just fine. The question is about the mentioned Visual Studio API compile function which I call from within an Visual Studio extension.